# Sympy codegen: summed indexed functions

Tags: python, indexing, sum, code-generation, sympy

I'm struggling with what seems to be a simple problem in the python sympy module. Thus I suspect that I have misunderstood something - I hope you can help me.

My problem revolves around: sums of vectors (or at least indexed parameters), derivatives of these with respect to a specific matrix element and how to make this accessible through the autowrap functionality.

Example:

```
from sympy import Eq, IndexedBase, symbols, Idx, Sum, diff
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import autowrap
nc = symbols("nc", integer=True)
fout = symbols("fout")

n  = IndexedBase("n")
F  = IndexedBase("F")
i  = Idx("i", nc)
j  = Idx("j", nc)
F1 = symbols("F1")
N  = Sum(n[i],i)
F1 = Sum(F[i,j]*n[i]/N,i,j)
Funcout = Eq(fout,diff(F1,n[i]))

Testfunction = autowrap(Funcout)
```

Here I get the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: FIXME: No specialized handling of type <class 'sympy.concrete.summations.Sum'>
```

How do I use autowrap to generate the vector function with:
Output: [vector] where the i'th element corresponds to diff(F1,n[i])
Input: F and n of arbitrary sizes (but n[m] and F[m,m]).

But surely there must be a way to do summations over an arbitrary array size with sympy that plays well with the codegen module?

Context: I work with simulations based on large equation systems where some of the boundary conditions are defined by a series of first and second order derivatives from particular functions. Thus I want to write the main function in sympy, then generate the derivatives and finally get a fast implementation by using the codegen capabilities. This would probably save me half a years worth of work.